# I wanna add and remove active link on my sidebar with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, sidebar

I wanna make an add and remove active link when clicking on the links and move to the sections as it should with JavaScript. You may ignore some svg codes

HTML source code

```
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-header">
            <div class="brand-name-container text-white fw-bold text-center">
                <p class="navbar-brand">
                    Profile
                </p>
            </div>
        </div> 
    <div class="sidebar-list">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-center text-white fw-bold">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Main</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Education</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Achievements & Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"> 
        <div class="navigationBar">    
            <button id="sidebarToggle" class="btn sidebarToggle">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Main text-center fw-bold">
    <span class="leftquote">"</span> <center>Success</center> is nothing more than a <br>few simple disciplines practiced <center>everyday.</center> <span class="rightquote">"</span>
    <span class="author">
        ~~~Jim Rohn~~~
    </span>
</div>

<div class="About">
    <h2 class="display-6 fw-bold">About me</h2>
        <img src="C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Portfolio\IMG\IMG_20220628_112625.jpg" class="avatar" alt="photo">
    <h1 class="display-6 fw-bold text-center">
        Carson Lee
    </h1>
    
</div>
<svg id="wave" style="transform:rotate(0deg); transition: 0.3s" viewBox="0 0 1440 340" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="sw-gradient-0" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
            <stop stop-color="rgba(62, 243, 236.869, 1)" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgba(11, 255, 180.612, 1)" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path style="transform:translate(0, 0px); opacity:1" fill="url(#sw-gradient-0)" d="M0,0L48,17C96,34,192,68,288,102C384,136,480,170,576,175.7C672,181,768,159,864,136C960,113,1056,91,1152,107.7C1248,125,1344,181,1440,221C1536,261,1632,283,1728,243.7C1824,204,1920,102,2016,79.3C2112,57,2208,113,2304,153C2400,193,2496,215,2592,204C2688,193,2784,147,2880,124.7C2976,102,3072,102,3168,130.3C3264,159,3360,215,3456,215.3C3552,215,3648,159,3744,130.3C3840,102,3936,102,4032,119C4128,136,4224,170,4320,170C4416,170,4512,136,4608,153C4704,170,4800,238,4896,255C4992,272,5088,238,5184,221C5280,204,5376,204,5472,187C5568,170,5664,136,5760,102C5856,68,5952,34,6048,51C6144,68,6240,136,6336,141.7C6432,147,6528,91,6624,102C6720,113,6816,193,6864,232.3L6912,272L6912,340L6864,340C6816,340,6720,340,6624,340C6528,340,6432,340,6336,340C6240,340,6144,340,6048,340C5952,340,5856,340,5760,340C5664,340,5568,340,5472,340C5376,340,5280,340,5184,340C5088,340,4992,340,4896,340C4800,340,4704,340,4608,340C4512,340,4416,340,4320,340C4224,340,4128,340,4032,340C3936,340,3840,340,3744,340C3648,340,3552,340,3456,340C3360,340,3264,340,3168,340C3072,340,2976,340,2880,340C2784,340,2688,340,2592,340C2496,340,2400,340,2304,340C2208,340,2112,340,2016,340C1920,340,1824,340,1728,340C1632,340,1536,340,1440,340C1344,340,1248,340,1152,340C1056,340,960,340,864,340C768,340,672,340,576,340C480,340,384,340,288,340C192,340,96,340,48,340L0,340Z">
    </path>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="sw-gradient-1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
            <stop stop-color="rgba(141.031, 227.999, 216.215, 1)" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgba(11, 255, 213.673, 1)" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path style="transform:translate(0, 50px); opacity:0.9" fill="url(#sw-gradient-1)" d="M0,272L48,249.3C96,227,192,181,288,187C384,193,480,249,576,260.7C672,272,768,238,864,209.7C960,181,1056,159,1152,124.7C1248,91,1344,45,1440,34C1536,23,1632,45,1728,90.7C1824,136,1920,204,2016,209.7C2112,215,2208,159,2304,124.7C2400,91,2496,79,2592,79.3C2688,79,2784,91,2880,90.7C2976,91,3072,79,3168,96.3C3264,113,3360,159,3456,192.7C3552,227,3648,249,3744,215.3C3840,181,3936,91,4032,51C4128,11,4224,23,4320,34C4416,45,4512,57,4608,96.3C4704,136,4800,204,4896,198.3C4992,193,5088,113,5184,90.7C5280,68,5376,102,5472,96.3C5568,91,5664,45,5760,45.3C5856,45,5952,91,6048,107.7C6144,125,6240,113,6336,130.3C6432,147,6528,193,6624,198.3C6720,204,6816,170,6864,153L6912,136L6912,340L6864,340C6816,340,6720,340,6624,340C6528,340,6432,340,6336,340C6240,340,6144,340,6048,340C5952,340,5856,340,5760,340C5664,340,5568,340,5472,340C5376,340,5280,340,5184,340C5088,340,4992,340,4896,340C4800,340,4704,340,4608,340C4512,340,4416,340,4320,340C4224,340,4128,340,4032,340C3936,340,3840,340,3744,340C3648,340,3552,340,3456,340C3360,340,3264,340,3168,340C3072,340,2976,340,2880,340C2784,340,2688,340,2592,340C2496,340,2400,340,2304,340C2208,340,2112,340,2016,340C1920,340,1824,340,1728,340C1632,340,1536,340,1440,340C1344,340,1248,340,1152,340C1056,340,960,340,864,340C768,340,672,340,576,340C480,340,384,340,288,340C192,340,96,340,48,340L0,340Z">
    </path>
</svg>

<svg id="wave2" style="transform:rotate(180deg); transition: 0.3s" viewBox="0 0 1440 490" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="sw-gradient-0" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
            <stop stop-color="rgba(62, 243, 236.869, 1)" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgba(11, 255, 180.612, 1)" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path style="transform:translate(0, 0px); opacity:1" fill="url(#sw-gradient-0)" d="M0,0L60,24.5C120,49,240,98,360,147C480,196,600,245,720,253.2C840,261,960,229,1080,196C1200,163,1320,131,1440,155.2C1560,180,1680,261,1800,318.5C1920,376,2040,408,2160,351.2C2280,294,2400,147,2520,114.3C2640,82,2760,163,2880,220.5C3000,278,3120,310,3240,294C3360,278,3480,212,3600,179.7C3720,147,3840,147,3960,187.8C4080,229,4200,310,4320,310.3C4440,310,4560,229,4680,187.8C4800,147,4920,147,5040,171.5C5160,196,5280,245,5400,245C5520,245,5640,196,5760,220.5C5880,245,6000,343,6120,367.5C6240,392,6360,343,6480,318.5C6600,294,6720,294,6840,269.5C6960,245,7080,196,7200,147C7320,98,7440,49,7560,73.5C7680,98,7800,196,7920,204.2C8040,212,8160,131,8280,147C8400,163,8520,278,8580,334.8L8640,392L8640,490L8580,490C8520,490,8400,490,8280,490C8160,490,8040,490,7920,490C7800,490,7680,490,7560,490C7440,490,7320,490,7200,490C7080,490,6960,490,6840,490C6720,490,6600,490,6480,490C6360,490,6240,490,6120,490C6000,490,5880,490,5760,490C5640,490,5520,490,5400,490C5280,490,5160,490,5040,490C4920,490,4800,490,4680,490C4560,490,4440,490,4320,490C4200,490,4080,490,3960,490C3840,490,3720,490,3600,490C3480,490,3360,490,3240,490C3120,490,3000,490,2880,490C2760,490,2640,490,2520,490C2400,490,2280,490,2160,490C2040,490,1920,490,1800,490C1680,490,1560,490,1440,490C1320,490,1200,490,1080,490C960,490,840,490,720,490C600,490,480,490,360,490C240,490,120,490,60,490L0,490Z">
    </path>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="sw-gradient-1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="1" y2="0">
            <stop stop-color="rgba(117.837, 243.936, 226.85, 1)" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stop-color="rgba(11, 255, 213.673, 1)" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path style="transform:translate(0, 50px); opacity:0.9" fill="url(#sw-gradient-1)" d="M0,392L60,359.3C120,327,240,261,360,269.5C480,278,600,359,720,375.7C840,392,960,343,1080,302.2C1200,261,1320,229,1440,179.7C1560,131,1680,65,1800,49C1920,33,2040,65,2160,130.7C2280,196,2400,294,2520,302.2C2640,310,2760,229,2880,179.7C3000,131,3120,114,3240,114.3C3360,114,3480,131,3600,130.7C3720,131,3840,114,3960,138.8C4080,163,4200,229,4320,277.7C4440,327,4560,359,4680,310.3C4800,261,4920,131,5040,73.5C5160,16,5280,33,5400,49C5520,65,5640,82,5760,138.8C5880,196,6000,294,6120,285.8C6240,278,6360,163,6480,130.7C6600,98,6720,147,6840,138.8C6960,131,7080,65,7200,65.3C7320,65,7440,131,7560,155.2C7680,180,7800,163,7920,187.8C8040,212,8160,278,8280,285.8C8400,294,8520,245,8580,220.5L8640,196L8640,490L8580,490C8520,490,8400,490,8280,490C8160,490,8040,490,7920,490C7800,490,7680,490,7560,490C7440,490,7320,490,7200,490C7080,490,6960,490,6840,490C6720,490,6600,490,6480,490C6360,490,6240,490,6120,490C6000,490,5880,490,5760,490C5640,490,5520,490,5400,490C5280,490,5160,490,5040,490C4920,490,4800,490,4680,490C4560,490,4440,490,4320,490C4200,490,4080,490,3960,490C3840,490,3720,490,3600,490C3480,490,3360,490,3240,490C3120,490,3000,490,2880,490C2760,490,2640,490,2520,490C2400,490,2280,490,2160,490C2040,490,1920,490,1800,490C1680,490,1560,490,1440,490C1320,490,1200,490,1080,490C960,490,840,490,720,490C600,490,480,490,360,490C240,490,120,490,60,490L0,490Z">
    </path>
</svg>

<div class="Education">
    <h3 class="display-6 fw-bold">Education</h3>
    
    <img src="https://www.ucsi.edu.my/LANDINGPAGE/ucsiedu/img/ucsi_university_2.jpg" class="campus">
    <img src="https://commchest.org.my/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/sjkc-on-pong-1.jpg" class="campus2">
    
        <table class="table-responsive table table-hover">
            <thead class="table-dark ">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Campuses</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>SJK (C) On Pong 1 (Chinese school)
                        <br>
                        *Primary Education
                    </td>
                    <td>The Abundant Resource Center
                        <br>
                        *Secondary Education
                    </td>
                    <td>UCSI University
                        <br>
                        *Tertiary Education
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table-responsive table table-hover">
            <thead class="table-success">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Level of Education</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-success">
                <tr>
                    <td>UPSR (Ujian Penilaian Sekolah Rendah)</td>
                    <td>IGCSE (grade 11)</td>
                    <td>Foundation in Science (Graduated)</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" id="wave3" viewBox="0 0 1440 700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150">
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="53%" y1="0%" x2="47%" y2="100%">
                    <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#ff6900ff"></stop>
                    <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#fcb900ff"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,700 C 0,700 0,350 0,350 C 130.78571428571428,314.9642857142857 261.57142857142856,279.92857142857144 359,313 C 456.42857142857144,346.07142857142856 520.5,447.25 656,444 C 791.5,440.75 998.4285714285713,333.0714285714286 1141,300 C 1283.5714285714287,266.9285714285714 1361.7857142857142,308.46428571428567 1440,350 C 1440,350 1440,700 1440,700 Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gradient)" class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150 path-0"></path>
        </svg>
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" id="wave4" viewBox="0 0 1440 700" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="transition duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150">
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="53%" y1="0%" x2="47%" y2="100%">
                    <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#ff6900ff"></stop>
                    <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#fcb900ff"></stop>
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 0,700 C 0,700 0,350 0,350 C 90.42820512820512,289.0076923076923 180.85641025641024,228.01538461538462 268,228 C 355.14358974358976,227.98461538461538 439.0025641025642,288.94615384615383 497,307 C 554.9974358974358,325.05384615384617 587.1333333333333,300.2 677,341 C 766.8666666666667,381.8 914.4641025641026,488.25384615384615 996,472 C 1077.5358974358974,455.74615384615385 1093.0102564102565,316.7846153846154 1156,276 C 1218.9897435897435,235.2153846153846 1329.4948717948719,292.60769230769233 1440,350 C 1440,350 1440,700 1440,700 Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="url(#gradient)" class="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out delay-150 path-0" transform="rotate(-180 720 350)"></path>
        </svg>
</div>

<div class="Achievements_Skills">
    <h4 class="display-6 fw-bold">Achievements</h3>

        <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/105184379/175819586-b2a06bd5-5b7f-4166-8ab9-9933b47d0c66.jpg" class="courseracert-1" alt="cert1">
            
        <img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/105184379/175817285-89816973-0d6b-4c48-941f-de04113c750e.jpg" class="courseracert-2" alt="cert2">
            

        <h4 class="display-6 fw-bold mt-5">My skills</h4>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark fw-bold">Coding Skills:</li>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal text-center">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
                            <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1488/PNG/512/5352-html5_102567.png" class="HTML5">
                            <br>
                            HTML5
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary">
                            <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/844/PNG/512/CSS3_icon-icons.com_67069.png" class="CSS3">
                            <br>
                            CSS3
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">
                            <img src="https://www.seekpng.com/png/full/80-803501_javascript-logo-logo-de-java-script-png.png" class="JS">
                            <br>
                            JavaScript
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group=item list-group-item">
                            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Bootstrap_logo.svg/512px-Bootstrap_logo.svg.png?20210507000024" class="BS5">
                            <br>
                            
                            BootStrap
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
                            <img src="https://www.logo.wine/a/logo/JQuery/JQuery-Logo.wine.svg" class="JQuery">
                            <br>
                            JQuery
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="shapes" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs" width="1340" height="1250" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1340 1250">
                <g mask="url(&quot;#SvgjsMask1091&quot;)" fill="none">
                    <rect width="1340" height="1250" x="0" y="0" fill="rgba(105, 7, 243, 1)"></rect>
                    <path d="M666.487,624.362C747.82,626.288,822.738,581.748,864.522,511.942C907.508,440.127,920.861,347.137,873.895,277.859C830.717,214.169,743.152,213.263,666.487,219.828C603.231,225.245,547.047,255.426,512.658,308.793C474.683,367.724,453.341,439.913,484.06,502.931C518.367,573.309,588.215,622.508,666.487,624.362" fill="rgba(86, 28, 142, 0.4)" class="triangle-float3"></path>
                    <path d="M1153.873,539.97C1187.092,537.755,1209.219,509.635,1225.872,480.806C1242.534,451.962,1256.956,418.17,1241.179,388.832C1224.792,358.361,1188.465,347.563,1153.873,346.929C1117.896,346.27,1079.969,355.048,1060.846,385.529C1040.691,417.656,1043.504,459.174,1063.073,491.662C1082.032,523.138,1117.209,542.415,1153.873,539.97" fill="rgba(86, 28, 142, 0.4)" class="triangle-float1"></path>
                    <path d="M1460.8475040603996 107.29109748324167L1135.2346227741873-73.60494767576512 1135.2346227741873 252.00793361044714z" fill="rgba(86, 28, 142, 0.4)" class="triangle-float2"></path>
                    <path d="M803.6132103326033 1065.4829209328218L550.9150473067577 821.4551414843949 559.5854308841764 1318.1810839586674z" fill="rgba(86, 28, 142, 0.4)" class="triangle-float3"></path>
                    <path d="M175.7675092020547 622.5689674116753L121.4194315514195 930.7922321228942 483.99077391327364 676.9170450623105z" fill="rgba(86, 28, 142, 0.4)" class="triangle-float2"></path>
                    <path d="M890.887,174.319C933.257,173.865,958.582,131.997,978.885,94.806C998.043,59.712,1012.622,19.8,994.769,-15.976C975.173,-55.244,934.767,-80.818,890.887,-81.531C845.799,-82.263,801.554,-59.581,780.992,-19.448C761.826,17.961,778.822,60.167,799.558,96.729C820.679,133.97,848.075,174.778,890.887,174.319" fill="rgba(86, 28, 142, 0.4)" class="triangle-float1"></path>
                </g>
                <defs>
                    <mask id="SvgjsMask1091">
                        <rect width="1340" height="1250" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
                    </mask>
                    <style>
                        @keyframes float1 {
                            0%{transform: translate(0, 0)}
                            50%{transform: translate(-10px, 0)}
                            100%{transform: translate(0, 0)}
                        }
            
                        .triangle-float1 {
                            animation: float1 5s infinite;
                        }
            
                        @keyframes float2 {
                            0%{transform: translate(0, 0)}
                            50%{transform: translate(-5px, -5px)}
                            100%{transform: translate(0, 0)}
                        }
            
                        .triangle-float2 {
                            animation: float2 4s infinite;
                        }
            
                        @keyframes float3 {
                            0%{transform: translate(0, 0)}
                            50%{transform: translate(0, -10px)}
                            100%{transform: translate(0, 0)}
                        }
            
                        .triangle-float3 {
                            animation: float3 6s infinite;
                        }
                    </style>
                </defs>
            </svg>
</div>

<div class="Projects">
    <h5 class="display-6 fw-bold">Projects</h5>
    <div class="card bg-secondary">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-header bg-warning">Responsive static restaurant webpage with BootStrap</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="https://carson3377.github.io/Module-3-assignment/static%20restaurant.html" target="_blank" class="card-link">https://carson3377.github.io/Module-3-assignment/static%20restaurant.html</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary">Registration form with HTML & CSS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="https://carson3377.github.io/Creative-Coderz-Form/form/Form.html" target="_blank" class="card-link">https://carson3377.github.io/Creative-Coderz-Form/form/Form.html</a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">Building a calculator with JavaScript</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="https://carson3377.github.io/Creative-Coderz-calculator/calculator/calculator.html" target="_blank" class="card-link">https://carson3377.github.io/Creative-Coderz-calculator/calculator/calculator.html</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-header bg-danger">Restaurant website with JavaScript & JQuery</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="https://carson3377.github.io/Module-5-assignment/index.html" target="_blank" class="card-link">https://carson3377.github.io/Module-5-assignment/index.html</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-header bg-white">Switching dark & light mode with JQuery</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="https://carson3377.github.io/Creative-Coderz-darkmode/Responsive%20week%204/index4.html" target="_blank" class="card-link">https://carson3377.github.io/Creative-Coderz-darkmode/Responsive%20week%204/index4.html</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" id="wave5" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <path d="M-27.19,-14.90 C159.06,108.08 359.06,-84.90 503.44,60.08 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #e7431a"></path>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" id="wave6" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <path d="M1.57,80.08 C90.93,251.08 302.18,33.08 551.55,175.08 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: #e7431a"></path>
</svg>

<div class="Contact">
    <h6 class="display-6 fw-bold">Contact</h6>
    <div class="container">
    </div>

</div>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" id="wave7" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <path d="M-62.19,-29.90 C175.93,109.08 567.18,4.10 552.18,-21.90 L502.81,163.08 L0.00,150.00 Z" style="stroke: none; fill: rgb(63, 63, 63);"></path>
</svg>
```

JavaScript source code here:

This accounts for the sidebarToggle when clicked on the toggle button it push back the sidebar to the side and it is completed.

```
 let sidebarToggle = document.querySelector(".sidebarToggle");
    sidebarToggle.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("active");
        document.getElementById("sidebarToggle").classList.toggle("active");
    })
```

But this has problem which accounts for the add and remove active link

```
var switchMainToActive = function() {
var classes = document.querySelectorAll('.Main').className;
classes = classes.replace(newRegExp('active', 'g'), '');
document.querySelectorAll('.Main').className = classes;

classes = document.querySelector('.About').className;

if (classes.indexOf('active') == -1) {
    classes += 'active';
    document.querySelectorAll('.About').className = classes;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and here you are trying to get its `className`:

```js
var classes = document.querySelectorAll('.Main').className;
```

That doesn't work because `NodeList` doesn't have the `className` property.
You can either use `querySelector` or iterate through every element of the `NodeList` to manage the classes.

You can also use `classList.remove` to remove the `active` class. And also `classList.contains` to check whether `About` has the class `active`. Here is the edited code:

```js
var switchMainToActive = function() {
    var main = document.querySelector('.Main');
    main.classList.remove('active');
    var about = document.querySelector('.About');
    if (about.classList.contains('active')) {
        about.classList.add('active');
    }
};
```

But I don't understand why that function is called `switchMainToActive` because it actually doesn't do that. It also doesn't remove the `active` class. I would use `classList.toggle` and change the function name, too (function name is for your choice).

Code:

```js
var toggleClasses = function() {
    var main = document.querySelector('.Main');
    main.classList.toggle('active');
    var about = document.querySelector('.About');
    about.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

Comment: It's not working either when I clicked on the sidebar list, doesn't seems to be active or remove. Would you also help check the sidebarToggle one?

Comment: @LeeCarson It's unclear what you want. Can you show the piece of code where you call the `switchMainToActive` function?

Comment: The code is shown above both the switchMainToActive function and the sidebarToggle function and the HTML code as well. The main thing I want is to make the sidebar lists to be active when I clicked on them or when I scrolled to the section

Comment: Ok. Can you show me the code where you call that function?

Answer (score 0):

I use scrollTo property for the scrolling effect, but this is not really professional and this is my own way. However, I need someone who is capable of making a scrolling effect when clicking on the sidebar, moving to a specific section of the page and trying to make the sidebar to be active with JavaScript.

```
function scrollMain() {
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

function scrollAbout() {
window.scrollTo(0, 800);
}

function scrollEducation() {
window.scrollTo(0, 1880);
}

function scrollAchieve() {
window.scrollTo(0, 3000);
}

function scrollPro() {
window.scrollTo(0, 4850)
}

function scrollContact() {
window.scrollTo(0, 6000)
}
```

This is a question to my prior question, not the answer

Answer (score -1):

I dont know hot to do it with javascript,but if u are okay with css there you go

```
./#Class/IdName :: active{
```

if u want under line then

text-decoration-underline;

if u want to remove underline

text-decoration - none;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).